# How to get a Mesh from a Collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry for my bad English.

I have a 2D project in Unity3D and I need to get a **Mesh** object from a **Collider** that is not a **MeshCollider**.

Also I need to get a **Mesh** from a **PolygonCollider2D** and use it to make a **MeshFilter** for rendering...

Help me please, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Triangulator

Try a triangulator to receive the mesh from the points used. 
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator

Currently there's no proper way to access the generated mesh from the polygon collider system.